# Text on the bottom of its parent without top margin AND the text flows downward as content is added?

Tags: html, css

so I have the following mockup as a template for several products -

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9R0J2.png

**Note :** the text should always be aligned to the base of the container...

The DOM needs to be reused for several products with variable content per the mock. JavaScript will be used to insert the "savings" amount if applicable.

I need to mark up the DOM and CSS so the text, if longer than what's in the mock, will flow downward and increase the container height, but the text also needs to stay along the bottom. The trick is, I can't use top margin to push the text down as the content length will vary. I want to do this with CSS only.

I want to note that positioning the text absolute, bottom: 0 will not work because additional text will flow upward. The same will happen if I use display: inline-block, vertical-align: bottom.

Demo code here - http://jsfiddle.net/cKPDd/
Of course not exactly like the mock - just need a working demo. I'm also adding a comment below with an extra link to get around SO's limits.

DOM -

```
/* To view what this should look like with longer text, see -http://i.imgur.com/Ivq9YzB.png */

<div class="product-container">

<div class="content-wrapper savings-quantity-content">
    <p class="savings">50% savings</p>
    <p class="quantity">500 things</p>
</div>

<div class="content-wrapper cost-content">
   <p class="cost">$99.99 total</p>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS -

```
.product-container {
    min-height: 110px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    width: 250px;
}

.content-wrapper {
    max-width: 140px;
}

.savings-quantity-content {
    float:left;
}

.cost-content {
    float: right;
}
```

Much appreciated!

Sue

Comment: please provide your code...or jsfiddle!

Comment: code added! any suggestions?

Comment: not suggestion....answer is coming up!! :)

Comment: is old browser support expected???? like IE7 or older??

Comment: Can you show an example of what it should look like if there was more information and it was being pushed down more etc.

Comment: @Ruddy : OP wants exactly like this => http://jsfiddle.net/cKPDd/9/ , text aligned to baseline but the thing is that i was expecting IE support too....couldn't get `position` to work out, can u suggest any css or any other idea mate???

Comment: Ruddy - Here is a mock of the same layout with more text - http://i.imgur.com/Ivq9YzB.png vs http://i.imgur.com/BErMOdw.png (minimal text).

Comment: NoobEditor - Actually, we are _not_ supporting IE 8 or less.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the better way, but it's work ;-) !!

```
body{font-size:15px;}
.product-container {min-height: 110px;border: 1px solid blue;width: 250px;}
.content-wrapper {max-width: 140px;display: inline-block;}
.savings-quantity-content {float:left;}
.cost-content {float: right;}
.savings{color: red;font-size: 0.7em;margin-top: 60px;margin-left: 10px;}
.quantity{font-size: 1.4em;margin-left: 10px;position: absolute;margin-top: -6px;}
.cost{font-size: 1.4em;position: relative;margin-top: 80px;margin-right: 10px;}
```

Envoy ! http://jsfiddle.net/cKPDd/2/

Comment: I cannot use margin-top for the content since some products will not have the "50% savings" text.

Comment: Also the absolute positioning on the quantity means the container will not expand as the text does. I do appreciate your time! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is too simple: you have not `clear`ed the float

<kbd>[**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/cKPDd/5/)</kbd>

Also, give `width:48%;` to `float`ed `div`s to align them properly

`<div class="clr"></div>`

```
.clr{
    clear:both;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="product-container">
    <div class="content-wrapper savings-quantity-content">
        <p class="savings">50% savings >50% savings>50% savings>50% savings>50% savings>50% savings>50% savings</p>
        <p class="quantity">500 things</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content-wrapper cost-content">
        <p class="cost">$99.99 total</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div> <!-- <- add this here -->
</div>
```

**EDIT**

IF IE7 or older support is not needed then :

[**solution demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cKPDd/11/)

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    min-height:100%; /* added */
}

.product-container {
    min-height: 110px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    width: 250px;
    display:table; /* added */
    height:100%; /* added */
}
.savings-quantity-content {
    width:48%;
    display:table-cell; /* added */
    height:100%; /* added */
    vertical-align:bottom; /* added */
}
.cost-content {
    width:48%;
    height:100%; /* added */
    display:table-cell; /* added */
    vertical-align:bottom; /* added */
}
```

Comment: This doesn't align my text along the bottom of the container. Compare http://i.imgur.com/BErMOdw.png and http://i.imgur.com/Ivq9YzB.png to see how the same DOM and CSS need to accomplish both mockups. My jsfiddle as-is shows both blocks of text top-aligned to each other, which is not what I need.

Comment: @sueanna : in the 2 images you marked, basically, there is more gap between the 2 text container and height of text differs....you pointing to that???

Comment: I'm referring to the vertical alignment of the text. $99.99 total needs to line up with 500 things. Then if the text is longer (for example - "500 things and many, many more" or "$99.99 plus  shipping"), the text should still be aligned at the bottom like in the mockup and flows down. I hope that helps.

Comment: I don't want the text to flow upward because it will run into the gears image that will appear in the middle.

Comment: Hi NoobEditor - I looked at your edit and unfortunately when the text gets longer, it moves upward to fill the above empty space. I need it to extend down so it doesn't get close to the product image that's in the mockup.

Comment: @sueanna : mmm....wait, will give you a markup....and plz respond bit early this time!! :)

Comment: let us [**continue this discussion in chat**](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46323/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-sueanna)

Comment: @sueanna : please come on chat using above link!! :)

Comment: half an hour i waited in chat, since your are a busy person to respond back, check this fiddle => jsfiddle.net/cKPDd/12 , make amendments in DOM and mark answer as accepted..regards!! :)

Comment: Hi NoobEditor - It was almost 2 am when I last posted here, so I decided to get some sleep. Your latest jsfiddle might work, but I'd have to consult our designers. Some of the images to be used in the final layout are even taller than what is in the mockup. I should have posted a better example. I'm sorry about that. So I was going to make the images as backgrounds since the text blocks need to appear to the left and right rather than directly below. I'll ask the designers if they can make the images simpler. Sometimes code solutions are more so project compromises with other teams :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work, Look [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fuFv2/)

```
.savings-quantity-content {
   display:inline-block;

}

.cost-content {
   display:inline-block;
   text-align:right;
   width:140px; 
}
```

Comment: This is close, but both blocks of text need to be docked at the bottom of the parent container (the finished layout will have padding on the parent as a buffer). If I apply your changes plus a background color to the text containers, you'll see they are not at the bottom of the parent. http://jsfiddle.net/fuFv2/1/

Comment: This works ok if the second line on the left is at least three lines long, but sometimes it will be just one or two.